# Record a Test Starting From Another Test Not working with Playwright VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright, playwright-test

So I followed the exact documentation - But I am not able include test code from one file to another one using this feature.

I selected one specific line in the test and then clicked Record from here. But strangely new record is created butcode up to that test line is not included.
I am not sure what mistake I am making. I tried selecting the entire line, placing cursor on the line but nothing works.

This is what official documentation says - Use the Record from here button to record a test from a specific line in your test file. This will open up a browser window and record the test from the line you selected. A new test file will now be created with the name test-2.spec.ts and will include the test code up to the selected line of the test file where you ran the Record from here button. You can then continue to generate the new test by clicking around in the browser window.